# Using a VPS as a DNS Server to Point it to itself

Tags: dns, apache2, vps

I recently purchased a VPS and I got a free domain (.tk). Now, I wanted to create a domain name server on my VPS, for the .tk domain; this DNS Server should point it to itself.

I followed [this URL](http://crm.vpscheap.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=10) but in vain. It does not work. How do I setup my VPS so that whenever I enter myname.tk in a browser it resolved to my VPS' IP address and renders the pages?

Comment: Does it resolve to your IP when you ping domain name  ?

Comment: It resolves to 127.0.0.1#53 and gives an error